# How can we pass data from another file to the feature file in cucumber-protractor frame work

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor -cucumber frame work with protractor 5.2.2. and cucumber 3.2.1.  My feature file is given below

```
When I go to "login" 
And I enter "devleena" in ".username"
And I enter "Pass123" in ".password"
And I click on ".sub-btn-login"
Then I should be at the "dashboard"
```

I have to pass these login credentials and locators from another file(like json file).So that if any changes occurs, we can make that changes in one place only. Thank in advance.

Comment: Anyone having idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using cucumber in the wrong way. Its a BDD framework, meaning that you have to describe behaviour in your test scenarios. You are writing test scripts in cucumber, which are going to make your life hard when maintaining the scripts as well.

What you need instead is something like:

```
When I login as "devleena" with password "Pass123"
Then the dashboard should be shown
```

Or

```
When I login as devleena
Then the dashboard should be shown
```

In the second case you are going to create a method for logging in a devleena and handle the username and password in your code.

This way, you can use the Background function of cucumber. Within the background function you can say:

```
Background: Login as devleena
Given I login as devleena
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Actually my requirement is pass the test data from a file to feature file.

Comment: In that case I am afraid the bdd frameworks do not provide an option to do this..